# Regular expression to evaluate following string

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

I am getting a user input in the form of

> key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3

and there can be any number of key value pairs,

I have written following regular expression to evaluate above string.

```
[a-z0-9]+(:|=)[a-z0-9]+
```

but I am not so sure , how to check the multiple of key value pairs, this string I have written can evaluate one key value pair, I want it make it evaluate hole string of key value pairs. highly appreciate any advice on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
([a-z0-9]+(:|=)[a-z0-9]+,?)+
```

To remove a trailing comma

```
if(str.substr(-1) === ',')
  str = str.substr(0, str.length - 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, the last comma should not be present at the end of the last key value pair, how to put the constrain on that

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex [`(\w+)[:=](\w+),?`](https://regex101.com/r/CARyoG/2), in which group 1 matches the key and group 2 matches the values.

You can also use split, it might be faster.

```
var input = "your input";
var pairs = input.split(",")
for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var parts = pairs[i].split(/[:=]/);
    var key = parts[0];
    var value = parts[1]
}
```

Comment: hanks for the solution, the last comma should not be present at the end of the last key value pair, how to put the constrain on that

Comment: What do you mean, you want to remove extra comma at the end?

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to (ab)use `replace` to do the job in one shot:

```js
str = "key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3"

re = /(\w+)[:=](\w+)/g

obj = {}

str.replace(re, (_, $1, $2) => obj[$1] = $2)

console.log(obj)
```